# Laptops hangs after a specified time

Tags: hp-pavilion, laptop-repair

[image]HP pavillion ab-1035ax is the laptop model. It boots properly, goes to the desktop screen after 5 mins of working laptop gets stuck.Sometimes boot file gets corrupted had to reinstall OS. The process repeats. The mouse stops moving, only option is to force shutdown the system.Any solutions for this?.Attached memtest below which gets stuck at this particular point.

Comment: Sounds like a faulty HDD, CPU overheating or RAM issue. Have you run Memtest or Prime95 to check your RAM or CPU? Any SMART errors on the HDD?

Comment: Inbuilt HDD test says it passed. Yes CPU heats a lot. RAM works perfect.

Comment: Faulty power supply is also possible ...

Comment: Ok so CPU overheating, could be blocked vents or you need to re-apply the thermal paste.

Comment: Unable to complete Memtest. While doing it the system stucks after some time. Unable to finish the test.

Comment: It might be useful to tell us which OS, and which version number.

Comment: Both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10

Comment: @spikey_richie Added memtest86 screenshot